# Sum of a subquery in NHibernate

Tags: sql, nhibernate

I am using NHibernate 3.3.1.4000.

Here's what I would like to achieve:

```
SELECT sum(tr_time)
FROM (SELECT seg.translation_time as tr_time
      FROM "TRANSLATION" seg
      WHERE seg.translation_time > 0 and seg.fk_id_language = 34
      ORDER BY seg.translation_time ASC
      LIMIT 1000) as subquery
```

The easiest way, using LINQ to NHibernate, fails with a `NotSupportedException`:

```
session.Query<Translation>()
       .Where(s => s.Language == language && s.TranslationTime > 0)
       .OrderBy(s => s.TranslationTime)
       .Take(1000)
       .Select(s => s.TranslationTime)
       .Sum(s => s);
```

I was able to produce this SQL:

```
SELECT sum(this_.translation_time) as y0_
FROM "TRANSLATION" this_
WHERE this_.id in (SELECT this_0_.id as y0_
                   FROM "TRANSLATION" this_0_
                   WHERE  this_0_.fk_id_language = 34
                       and this_0_.translation_time > 0                       
                   ORDER  BY this_0_.translation_time asc
                   LIMIT 1000)
```

with the following query:

```
session.QueryOver<Translation>(() => translationAlias)
       .WithSubquery.WhereProperty(s => s.Id)
                    .In(QueryOver.Of<Translation>(() => translationSubAlias)
                                 .Where(s => s.Language == language)
                                 .Where(s => s.TranslationTime > 0)
                                 .Select(s => s.Id)
                                 .OrderBy(s => s.TranslationTime).Asc
                                 .Take(1000))
       .Select(Projections.ProjectionList()
                          .Add(Projections.Sum(Projections.Property(() => translationAlias.TranslationTime))))
       .FutureValue<Int32>();
```

However, that's obviously not ideal as the `WHERE ... IN` clause is not necessary.

I tried things like

```
session.QueryOver<Translation>(() => translationAlias)
       .Select(Projections.ProjectionList()
          .Add(Projections.Sum(
                  Projections.Alias(
                     Projections.SubQuery(
                         QueryOver.Of<Translation>(() => translationSubAlias)
                                  .Where(() => translationSubAlias.Language == language)
                                  .Where(() => translationSubAlias2.TranslationTime > 0)
                                  .Select(Projections.Property("TranslationTime"))), "tr_time"))))
       .FutureValue<Int32>()
```

but it generates this SQL:

```
SELECT sum((SELECT this_0_.translation_time as y0_
FROM "TRANSLATION" this_0_
WHERE this_0_.fk_id_language = 34 and this_0_.translation_time > 0)) as y0_
FROM "TRANSLATION" this_
```

which the database server rejects with the following error message: **more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression**

I don't really care which method I would eventually use (LINQ, QueryOver, Criteria API) as long as it allows future queries.

Comment: Which version of nhibernate you are using ?

Comment: I am using NHibernate 3.3.1.4000.

Answer (score 0):

Any chance it is not returning any values? If that is the case, you need to make TranslationTime nullable:

```
session.Query<Translation>()
   .Where(s => s.Language == language && s.TranslationTime > 0)
   .OrderBy(s => s.TranslationTime)
   .Take(1000)
   .Select(s => s.TranslationTime)
   .Sum(s => (int?) s);
```

Notice the "int?" cast, assuming TranslationTime is of type int.